# Removing an option based on text instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I want to remove an option from an select based on the text of the option.

I tried using this line of code:

```
$('#list_' + id + ' option[text="' + alias + '"]').remove();
```

Sadly this doesn't work for me, as it removes nothing. If I use `value` instead of `text` it works, but I was wondering how I can do this using `text`.

```js
// Removing based on text doesnt work.

$('.removeByText').click(function() {

    $('#list option[text="Option2"]').remove();

});

// Removing based on value works.

$('.removeByValue').click(function() {

    $('#list option[value="2"]').remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='list'>
  <option value='1'>Option1</option>
  <option value='2'>Option2</option>
  <option value='3'>Option3</option>
  <option value='4'>Option4</option>
</select>

<button class='removeByText'>removeByText</button>

<button class='removeByValue'>removeByValue</button>
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: I made an example in the live demo feature, hope this helps. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`option` elements don't have a `text` attribute. If you want to do it this way, you could use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("#list_" + id + " option:contains(" + alias + ")").remove();
```

...but that does a substring match. Probably you'll want to [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("#list_" + id + " option")
    .filter(function() {
        return this.textContent === alias;
    })
    .remove();
```

Live Example using `filter`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const id = "example";
    const alias = "B";
    console.log(`Removing '${alias}'...`);
    $("#list_" + id + " option")
        .filter(function() {
            return this.textContent === alias;
        })
        .remove();
}, 800);
```

```html
<select id="list_example" size="3">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```